# How to write input method mim file for ibus-m17n?

Tags: linux

I want to write a new input method for iBus. Specifically for ibus-m17n.

Can somebody point me to some web pages that help to understand the format of mim files used for ibus-m17n?

Answer (score 3):

Well there is the [doc](http://www.nongnu.org/m17n/manual-en/m17nDBTutorial.html) and look at layout already created [MIMs](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/m17n/m17n-db.git/tree/MIM). They also have a mailing list. 
Its some form of lisp, I havent done anything more than simple keymappings myself.